# Save copy of worksheet as CSV with date in the save name

Tags: excel, vba, csv, save-as

I need to save a copy of the worksheet I'm using as a CSV file.

The save name is to be the date and the user's name. I set up variables to get this information.

I get

> Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error

on the line

```
Activeworkbook.saveAs Filename
```

Code is:

```
Sub SaveCSV()
rundate = DateTime.Now
runname = Application.UserName
savename = rundate & runname
sfilename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & savename & ".csv"

ActiveWorkbook.Save

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sfilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code to check the value of variables? Which line errors?

Comment: Stepped through it all and the variable values seem fine to me, the error is on the line: Activeworkbook.saveAs Filename....

Comment: What is the value of `sfilename`?

Comment: "C:\MACRO\06/04/2017 12:18:32Thomas Smith.csv"    I'm thinking now that the / in the date is causing the problem?

Comment: Don't think you are allowed `/` - try re-formatting the date or replacing with something else.

Comment: I will try to format it dd-mm-yyyy  - Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might also have trouble with colons.

Answer (score 0):

Value of rundate (based on default regional settings) will be  something similar to below:

> 3/12/2019 10:25:11

of which forward slash (/) & colon (:) are illegal characters as per the file name conventions in Windows.

To resolve this specific issue, use the below code to assign current-time to the rundate variable:

```
rundate = Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-MMM-YYYY_hh-mm-ss_")
```

Another good way is to use generic function because we don't always know what illegal characters are creating the trouble. Because there could be more illegal characters in the filename. Above approach is correct but it's not comprehensive list of illegal characters to remove or replace from the filename before saving it. For eg. these characters are missing from the array in your code -> : & . However it is advised to keep filename rid of other allowed special characters too.

Below, I am providing the function which returns a safe string that can be used to produce filename before saving.

```
Function ReplaceIllegalCharacters(strIn As String, strChar As String) As String
    Dim strSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    strSpecialChars = "~""#%&*:<>?{|}/\[]" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

    For i = 1 To Len(strSpecialChars)
        strIn = Replace(strIn , Mid$(strSpecialChars, i, 1), strChar)
    Next

    ReplaceIllegalCharacters = strIn 
End Function
```

Specifically, in your code, replace the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line with this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ReplaceIllegalCharacters(sfilename, "_") & _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```